# Projecting LAS to local coordinates using lastools

Tags: coordinate-system, lidar, las

Is it possible to project LAS files using Open source tools eg. lastools if using a less common coordinatesystem like local swedish espg: 3008 as destination and espg: 3006 as source?

I see 3008 is not listed in the LAS tools project drop down.

Is it still possible with some other open source solution like fusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [Transform CRS LiDAR point clouds in lidR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64083797/3338646) and define the [SWERF99 TM source -- destination coordinate transformation](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/sweref99-tm/) directly (instead of using the EPSG if the CRS is not listed), by defining the corresponding [proj4 or CYS formats](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics/spatial-data-r/understand-epsg-wkt-and-other-crs-definition-file-types/).

[Liblas](https://liblas.org/utilities/las2las.html) has also capabilities to transform data using the option `-a_srs` for the source dataset and `-t_srs` for the destination dataset, with a the corresponding [proj definitions](https://proj.org/) as used by the other GDAL tools. [Liblas](https://liblas.org/compilation.html#gdal) is a little bit outdated byt compiled against `GDAL` and `Proj4`.

Comment: Thanks, Will have a look at those options.